# JQUERY: In .each loop find class

Tags: jquery, this, each, contains

I need check every .archive_blocks for containing .archive_blocks_fa_active.
If is it true, apply css to .archive_blocks_sa.

```
<div class="archive_blocks">
    <a href="#" class="archive_blocks_fa_active">
        <img width="142" height="142" src="#">
    </a>
    <div class="archive_blocks_name">
        <a href="#" class="archive_blocks_sa">Ilustrations</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
 $('.archive_blocks').each(function(){

    if ( $("a.archive_blocks_fa_active").parents(this).length == 1 ) { 
        alert('OK'); 
    } else {        
        alert('NO');    
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, can't you just do this and not bother with the `each`:

```
$(".archive_blocks a.archive_blocks_fa_active")
    .closest(".archive_blocks")
    .find(".archive_blocks_sa")
    .addClass("whatever");
```

This uses a descendant selector which matches any `a.archive_blocks_fa_active` element that is a descendant of an `.archive_blocks` element. It then finds the related `.archive_blocks_sa` (there would be other ways of doing that, perhaps using `parent` and `next` if you prefer) and then adds the class.

Comment: @Vital - Not sure what you mean... I did read all of the question! If I have misunderstood what you're trying do, please explain.

Comment: First code was more closer to my needs: 
$('.archive_blocks .archive_blocks_fa_active').parent().find('a.archive_blocks_sa').css('background','#000');

But all codes are working great :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `has()` method reduces the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element.

```
$('.archive_blocks').each(function(){
   if ($(this).has(".archive_blocks_fa_active").length) { 
        $(this).find('.archive_blocks_sa').addClass('className'); 
   } 
});
```

Comment: This will add the class to all `.archive_blocks_sa`.  I think you meant to use `find` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.archive_blocks .archive_blocks_fa_active').parent().find('a.archive_blocks_sa').css(...);
```

Comment: Its working :)) But can you explain me a lil bit , how it is working ? :D

Comment: it gets all .archive_blocks_fa_active classes, that are children of .archive_blocks classes, then gets the parent node of each of those, then finds the .archive_blocks_sa classes in descendant nodes from those, then does whatever you want to them ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.archive_blocks').has(".archive_blocks_fa_active")
                    .find('.archive_blocks_sa')
                    .css({...});
```